# Nokogiri add attribute to an html tag without damaging its content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm new to ruby and need to parse html content and update it as required (add an attribute to 'body' tag). I have written the following code

```
def index
    url = "/home/employee/index.html"
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(url)
    doc.at_css("body").set_attribute("ng-init", "menu.inspired = 'true'")
    File.open('/home/employee/index.txt','w') {|f| doc.write_html_to f}
    @content=doc.to_html
end
```

The output written in the file is the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body ng-init="menu.inspired = 'true'"><p>/home/employee/index.html</p></body></html>
```

The output file contains the added attribute, but the content of the html file seems to be overwritten. So I need to figure out where is the mistake I have made.

Answer (score 1):

Your are not actually manipulating the document from the file `/home/employee/index.html` - Rather `Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse(url)` creates a skeleton HTML document with the body `"/home/employee/index.html"`.

You need to read the document from file first.

```
def index
    # note that this is a file path! Not an URL.
    path = "/home/employee/index.html"
    doc = File.open(path) { |f| Nokogiri::HTML(f) }
    doc.at_css("body").set_attribute("ng-init", "menu.inspired = 'true'")
    File.open(path,'w') {|f| doc.write_html_to f}
    @content=doc.to_html
end
```

See:

- [Nokogiri docs: Parsing an HTML/XML Document](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html)